# Message: Declaration of MY_Lang::line() should be compatible with that of CI_Lang::line()

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I uploaded a project on my server and got this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Runtime Notice
>
> Message: Declaration of MY_Lang::line() should be compatible with that of CI_Lang::line()
>
> Filename: core/MY_Lang.php
>
> Line Number: 94
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/qnscompa/public_html/erp/index.php
> Line: 292
> Function: require_once

- on line 292 this code is written..

  require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';

Comment: Could you edit your question to share some of the project, in particular around line 292? It's hard to help you otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

`MY_Lang::line()` has different arguments, or a different access level (public/private/protected) than `CI_Lang::line()`.

Having the same exact argument default values is important as well. For example, `parentClass::customMethod($thing = false)` and `childClass::customMethod($thing)` would trigger the error, because the child's method hasn't defined a default value for the first argument.